# Date Time on x-axis using JFreeChart

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc, graph, jfreechart

I would like to create a graph using data from a database (Oracle).
The dataset contains `DateTimeStamp` values and numeric values
The `DateTimeStamp` values are for intervals of 15 minutes and usually extend for a period greater than one calendar day.
The `DateTimeStamp` values need to be graphed against the X-axis and the data values (numeric) will be graphed against the Y-yxis.
The x-axis major tic marks should be the calendar days.
I have purchased the enterprise version of `JFreeChart` but the username password provided does not allow me to ask questions on their [forum](http://www.jfree.org/forum/index.php), and sending email to the owner results in no response.

Thanks for any help you can offer. A working code block/snippet would be ideal and much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`JDBCXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html), which [uses](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html#line.326) the query's `ResultSetMetaData` to recognize `Types` related to date and time. Complete examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24762078/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592754/230513).

[image]

As an aside, access to the [support forum](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) is free; just click the [register](http://www.jfree.org/forum/index.php) link.