# How to pass a string value of java to sql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I am trying to create this sql query in Java Netbeans:

```
SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE NAME LIKE '%SOMETHING%'
```

I am using Prepared Statement like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM demo WHERE NAME LIKE ? ");
ps.setString(1, "%"+something+"%");
...
```

The problem is that "setString" doesnt work at all.
I discovered that the value of "'" is actually "\'" so  the query becomes

```
SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE NAME LIKE \'%SOMETHING%\'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "like" wildcard in prepared statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247970/using-like-wildcard-in-prepared-statement)

Comment: Possibly your Solution is here: [passing java string variable in mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644882/passing-java-string-variable-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String sql = "select * from tablename like ?";
String sqlParasValue = "%" + "2015-03-23" + "%";
pStmt =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pStmt.setString(1, sqlParasValue);//Automatically add single quotes
pStmt.execute();
```

I try this on my code and it is work.
I uesd Spring boot + mybatis + postgresql

SQL Table & some data:

```
name   h    w    f
xi  182  53  li
1xi 181  52  [NULL]
li  180  51  xh
zs  165  50  li
xh  190  52  [NULL]
```

sql query:

```
select name from stu where name like '%x%'
```

sql query result:

```
name    h   w   f
xi  182 53  li
1xi 181 52  [NULL]
xh  190 52  [NULL]
```

java code

```
@Select("select name  from stu where name like #{name}")
List<String> test(@Param("name") String name);
List<String> s = serviceImpl.test("%x%");
for(String ss : s){
    System.out.println(ss);
}
```

console :

```
2017-04-06 14:02:47.607  INFO 7932 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-04-06 14:02:47.619  INFO 7932 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2017-04-06 14:02:47.759  INFO 7932 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (这个 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.getNetworkTimeout() 方法尚未被实作。)
2017-04-06 14:02:47.777  INFO 7932 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
xi
1xi
xh
2017-04-06 14:02:47.848  INFO 7932 --- [           main] com.ium.um.Application                   : Started Application in 5.911 seconds (JVM running for 6.416)
```

Comment: I ve tried it. It doesnt work.When i use integers it works fine but when i use strings it doesnt. Is there anyway to avoid the backslash of the apostrophe value? I want this one " ' " to be the same and not " \' "